# Elasticsearch match an array of strings

Tags: elasticsearch

My Elasticsearch (v5.4.1) documents have a `_patents` field as such :

```
{
    // (Other fields : title, text, date, etc.)
    ,
    "_patents": [
        {"cc": "US"},
        {"cc": "MX"},
        {"cc": "KR"},
        {"cc": "JP"},
        {"cc": "CN"},
        {"cc": "CA"},
        {"cc": "AU"},
        {"cc": "AR"}
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to build a query that would return only documents whose patents match an array of country codes.
For instance, if my filter is `["US","AU"]` I need to be returned all documents that have patents in `US` and in `AU`. Exclude documents that have `US` but not `AU`.

So far I have tried to add a "term" field to my current working query :

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                // (Other conditions here : title match, text match, date range, etc.) These work
                 ,
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "_patents.cc": [ // I tried just "_patents"
                            "US",
                            "AU"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Or this, as a filter :

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [...],
            "filter": {
                "terms": {
                    "_patents": [
                        "US",
                        "AU"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These queries and the variants I've tried don't produce an error, but return 0 result.

I can't change my ES document model to something easier to match, like `"_patents": [ "US","CA", "AU", "CN", "JP" ]` because this is a populated field. At indexation time, I populate and reference `Patent` documents that have many fields, including `cc`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution. The filtered country names have to be **lowercase**...

`"US"` returns no result, but `"us"` works, despite the indexed field being `"US"` ...... Faint -_-'

I also wrote the query this way :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "_patents.cc": "us"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "_patents.cc": "ca"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out why querying against an array of ints was working fine but with an array of strings it returned 0 results. This seems to be true when using "term/terms" but not when using "query." I guess it makes sense to facilitate exact matches but why not transform the query then? I'm missing something, obviously.

Answer (score 8):

This works for Uppercase and lowercase both..

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [ 
        {
          "match": {
            "_patents.cc": "au"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "_patents.cc": "us"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool, that's right, thanks :) I didn't know that "term" worked only with lowercase.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. Do you know if there's a "cleaner" way of doing it where we don't have to repeat the "match" clause ?

Answer (score 6):

My version of elasticsearch Version is 6.0.1. I am using this approach:

```
GET <your index>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
        "query_string": {
          "query": "cc:us OR cc:ca"
        }
      }]
    }    
  }
}
```