# ElasticSearch array data match multiple properties in nested element with AND condition

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm facing a problem where I have two documents each containing an array of objects. I like to search for one document containing two properties for a nested object (matching both at the same time in the same object) but I always get both documents.

I created the documents with:

```
POST /respondereval/_doc
{
  "resp_id": "1236",
  "responses": [
     {"key": "meta","text":"abc"},
     {"key": "property 1", "text": "yes"},
     {"key": "property 2", "text": "yes"},
  ]
}

POST /respondereval/_doc
{
  "resp_id": "1237",
  "responses": [
     {"key": "meta","text":"abc"},
     {"key": "property 1", "text": "no"},
     {"key": "property 2", "text": "yes"},
  ]
}
```

I defined an index for them to prevent ES to flat out the objects like this:

```
PUT /respondereval
{
  "mappings" : {
    "properties": {
      "responses" : {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I now like to search for the first document (`resp_id 1236`) with the following query:

```
GET /respondereval/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "responses",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "responses.key": "property 1" } },
            { "match": { "responses.text": "yes" } }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This should only return one element which matches both conditions at the same time.

Unfortunatly, it always returns both documents. I assume it's because at some point, ES still flattens the values in the nested objects arrays into something like this (simplified):

```
resp_id 1236: "key":["gender", "property 1", "property 2"], "text:["abc", "yes", "yes"]
resp_id 1237: "key":["gender", "property 1", "property 2"], "text:["abc", "no", "yes"]
```

which both contain the `property1` and `yes`.

What is the correct way to solve this so that only documents are returned which contains an element in the objects array which matches both conditions (`"key": "property 1" AND "text": "yes"`) at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your mapping. You have text mapping which uses standard analyser by default.

Standard analyzer creates tokens on whitespaces. So

`property 1` will be tokenised as

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "property",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 8,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "1",
            "start_offset": 9,
            "end_offset": 10,
            "type": "<NUM>",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Similarly `property 2` also.

Hence both the documents are returned.

And when you search for `yes`, it matched from second text in the second document. `property 1` matches `property` analysed token of second key in the document.

To make it work: - use `keyword` variation

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "responses",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "responses.key.keyword": "property 1" } },
            { "match": { "responses.text.keyword": "yes" } }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It would be proper:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "responses",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match_phrase": { "responses.key": "property 1" } },//phrase queries
            { "match": { "responses.text": "yes" } }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response +1. Your `keyword` example works as expected BUT what would be the correct way to resolve the mapping problem so that I can use the `responses.key` without the `keyword`?

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you directly tried the `must` query without **nested.path**

```js
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "responses.key": "property 1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "responses.text": "yes"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought it's similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44586170/13907595) as per my knowledge. Isn't it similar to the above question?

Comment: It does not yield any results. @Gibbs answer is correct.